# PhantomJS and CasperJS what files do i need to put on my cpanel

Tags: php, ubuntu, phantomjs, cpanel, casperjs

Okay so i have finally build a test.js file that works on my ubuntu machine.

I just want to know how to i add phantomjs and casperjs on my cpanel and is there any way i can tet that they both work once on cpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SSH / Shell Access from your cPanel account if you have permissions.  Contact your host provider to be certain.

Here are the following commands that you can copy and paste into SSH to install dependencies, PhantomJS, and CasperJs.  Dependents tested using [docker.io](https://www.docker.io):

```
apt-get install -y libfreetype6 libfontconfig libreadline-dev wget tar bzip2 vim git  
mkdir -p /srv/var  
cd /srv/var
```

PhantomJS:

```
wget http://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2  
tar -xjf phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2  
ln -s `pwd`/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/  
phantomjs -v
```

CasperJS:

```
git clone https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git  
ln -s `pwd`/casperjs/bin/casperjs /usr/bin/  
casperjs --version
```

If they worked, You can type phantomjs -v or caspjer --version to verify installation.